# Running builds (gcc, make, cmake) inside identical docker, from same source gives binaries with different hashes

Tags: c++, c, gcc, makefile, cmake

I run into "interesting" issue. I am doing build automation for our project in Bamboo. I was quite sure that I am done and then someone asked: why builds from Friday night and Saturday night (no code changes) are different?
I have 2 remote builders. Both have same OS installed (Ubuntu) and updated at to the latest at the same time. Both has the same libraries installed. The compilation is inside docker (image imported from same source)
So I started looking into this and got to the point where I can observer the following:

- running compilation twice from same source on the same machine, starting new docker for each compilation produces identical (as per sha1sum) binaries.
- running compilation twice from same source on two different machines, produces different binaries.
  Source is in the folder of the same name and it is mounted into docker on the path with same name as well.
- running compilation on 1 PC with some HW spec, then taking the disk and connecting it to the different PC (with different HW spec) and running compilation from the same source again. Resulting binaries were identical.

Is it possible that somehow the code depends on exact OS image? or any other OS attribute? Any other idea?

It feels like chasing ghosts ...

EDIT: After trying to go step by step, I narrowed this down to cmake. That means: cmake made on two different machines differ (going to start 1-by-1 diffing now). If I put results of cmake of several machines and compile with make from there, I am always getting same binaries. So I believe that the problem is the way cmakefiles are written not compilation itself.

EDIT2: I now know that this is Qt 5.2.1 rcc being non-deterministic issue. During cmake rcc is run and among others calculates some hasheh. Difference in those hashes is what is causing the whole thing to non-deterministic.
If I do cmake and take content of it to 3 different machines and run compilation (make) there I got 100% identical (as per sha1sum) results.
I think that settles it here. Now I need either convince project to upgrade to newer version of Qt where I know how to make rcc deterministic or I need to find how to make rcc deterministic in 5.2.1.

Comment: Date and time ?

Comment: You may want to check out https://reproducible-builds.org/

Comment: Thanks. Date and time - I do not think so. It would not be "reproducible" on the same host. Going to check the link

Answer (score 0):

If you started with identical OS images, then your tests suggest a post-image configuration step introduced a change.  Review that configuration.  A trivial example would be the hostname.  I would diff any intermediate build artifacts, for instance, config.h or whatever cmake writes its output.  Try run strings on two binaries (that differ), then diff that output to see if you learn something.

https://tests.reproducible-builds.org/debian/index_issues.html might be very instructive, too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Good idea, but gcc and everything needed for compilation is in docker and dockers are the very same image. Double checked with command provided. Results are identical so that is not it.

Comment: Just to be clear where you using identical images on two different hosts?   You almost certainly do post-image configuration of the instance so you want to review those.  Have you tried diff'ing any of the intermediate build artifacts? For instance, maybe hostname differ and is written to a header file.

Comment: Yes, I have created this image by the means of dokcerfile, then I did docker save > image.tar, copied this tar to two builders and did load them. No changes into dokcer images once they are loaded. So the images are identical. I used --hostname to make sure host names of docker containers are identical. I am setting up two VM from identical OVA as we speak, so I will try with identical host hostnames soon. I am diffing one library that is produced, but diffing results of cmake sounds like a good idea (compilation goes: cmake .. , make ...)

Comment: Use that Debian link that I shared with you as a checklist.

Answer (score 0):

The results could be coincidence. Linking requires that all the required functions go into the executable, but the order is generally not constrained. This could very well depend on the order in which the object files appear on disk.

Comment: It's a small number of a tests op ran, of course, but different hardware would more likely trigger a race, no?

Comment: @AllanWind: True, as would running the test from a VFAT USB stick.

Comment: Hmm OK, so why it is ALYWAS the same on the same machine? I run that like 10 times to make sure no race conditions are present. Everything is on ext4.